# GNU Radio QT GUI Sink in C++

Tags: c++, qtgui, gnuradio

I'm trying to implement a simple QTGui sink (in my case a complex freq sink) in GNU Radio using C++.

I am having trouble finding any C++ examples.  Can someone point me to a simple example of how this might be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

All the graphical sinks you see are part of GNU Radio's [source tree](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio), and that is organized so that the QT stuff is in it's own [`gr-qtgui` submodule](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/tree/master/gr-qtgui); you'll find the public headers in `include/`, and the C++ implementations in `lib/`.

Now, "complex frequency sink" doesn't make any sense to me; for a complex signal, frequencies can be negative, but just as the time axis, the frequency axis is simply a part of the real numbers (and hence, not complex). So, I presume you don't want to see a Power Spectral Density (PSD) like QT GUI frequency sink displays, but just the Real and Imaginary part of a DFT; well, that's something best implemented directly as flow graph (doesn't matter if it's Python or C++; I used GRC to quickly get a Python flow graph):
[image: quick sketch]

The result is something like (FFT->Time sink with real and imaginary part top, Frequency sink bottom):

[image: graphical sinks]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Marcus.  At this time I am only trying to implement qt gui functions in C++ and am having trouble following how to do this from the generated python code.  The actual block/function used is not important ( I can use either one).  I mainly want to get ahold of a C++ (as opposed to grc or python) example that runs and plots a simple signal. ;-)

Comment: Well, GNU Radio is about connecting blocks that already exist, and writing new ones when necessary. In 99% of cases, you'd want to Python for the connecting. You really should not start with a GUI visualization if you want to learn how to write C++ blocks. They are really really complicated. Start with the [Guided Tutorials](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials) from 1 to 5, and you will have excellent understanding of how to write a C++ block!

Comment: Hi Marcus, I'm back to this but the Guided tutorials go into a lot of detail on writing OOT blocks,  I don't require that.  I just want to know the C++ calls to throw a plot (and a slider) on the screen.  I still cant find an example of this.

Comment: @RobertKraml it's pretty complicated to write a GUI block, so yes, you will need to know how to design a block to write a GUI block. No way around – anyway, there's no "entry-friendly" how to write a Qt visualization, so I can only recommend reading the source code in gr-qtgui/lib and /include.